# Large number of key-value set make connection slow in redis

Tags: node.js, redis

When I save 1 million Redis key as key-value

```
( Ex: TestKey:1 => 12, ...TestKey:1000000 => 24 )
```

it took about 8-20s to connect to my Redis server. Are there any limits on Redis?

I don't want to use `HMSET` because I want to set expire for these keys.

Can you guys explain to me what is going on?

( Redis is running in Docker )

Thank you.

Comment: How much connection do you have?
Read this useful article https://tech.trivago.com/2017/01/25/learn-redis-the-hard-way-in-production/

Comment: About 1000-2000 connection, I still can't figure out why it's slow when my Redis DB got bigger. It's works fine when Redis DB is small.

Comment: 1. One reason can be the size of your values, Bigger values will result in more IO. So more blocking time for the Redis main thread. 
@HVD

Comment: 2. Also 2000 connection is too much. This number of connections will waste the Redis's main thread's time(to manage the connections) You should use a proxy(such as twemproxy) or  replicate your Redis instance. 

Don't forget, Connections are expensive thing. It will be very good approach to open few connections and share them between your application's processes. 
@HVD

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Seem likes my problem is Redis library not closing the connection when I calling `client.quit()`. `quit()` command works in dev env, not work on the production. I solved it by changing the library.

Answer (score 2):

You may check [here](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) to see how "How fast is Redis?"

The following is executing 1 million `set` commands and it is 75K rps

```
redis-benchmark -n 1000000 -t set -q
SET: 74693.76 requests per second
```

If you use [pipeline](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) with 16 commands per `pipeline`, it is 845K rps **(11x)**

```
redis-benchmark -n 1000000 -t set -P 16 -q
SET: 845308.56 requests per second
```

with 64 commands per pipeline, it is 1.18 million rps **(15x)**

```
redis-benchmark -n 1000000 -t set -P 64 -q
SET: 1175088.12 requests per second
```

So if you want to execute large number of set commands you may use `pipeline` to speed up 10, 15 times depending on the number of commands in a single pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to debug the code and saw the Timeout error keep spamming. `Error: Redis connection to redis:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT 10.0.59.5:6379`

Comment: @HVD it is more likely to be related with network, configuration, docker settings etc which i am not familiar with (i focused on redis slowness issue). It would be more helpful if you open another question, people with more experience on this can help.

Comment: Thank you anyway. Don't know why this happened. Clearing all the keys and it's work fine again. And it's slow when having many data.

Comment: @HVD maybe it is related to the config of docker image - you may check with `info memory`, `memory doctor` or `slowlog` commands to identify. https://redis.io/commands/slowlog

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I solved it by changing the library. Seem like command `quit()` not work at all.